# Can someone help me with POST method in Slim Framework?

Tags: rest, slim

I can set a GET method in Slim to get data from my database but my problem is the POST method, i don't know how to use it correctly. I do some code like:

```
$app->post('/login',function() use ($app){

$inputs = json_decode($app->request()->getBody());
$result = json_encode($inputs);

return $result;
});
```

I wanna make a login function by POST method but this is just an example I want to show the data that have been sent in the body by json. I used Advanced Rest Client to test but the result is always "null".

I'm new to Rest and Slim Framework too. Thanks for any helpful idea !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `return` doesn't do anything in terms of viewing the output within that route callback function. use `print`, `print_r`, `echo`, `$app->response->setBody('Foo')`, or `$app->response->write('Foo')`

in terms of the post, did you try using `$data = $app->request()->post()` to get your data?